# Does Edge implement multiple specialist ServiceWorker instances?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

There is a fundamental design flaw with the current ServiceWorker design/implementations in that there is only ONE per UA per domain.

However, I believe Edge, notwithstanding their tardy arrival on the scene, has specialist SW instances for push, fetch, etc.

Can someone please confirm that Edge implements multiple, specialist SW instances?

EDIT 1

Ok, it might have been Safari/Webkit but reading [this](https://webkit.org/blog/8090/workers-at-your-service/) it looks like 1 process for all ServiceWorker threads plus another to monitor/start/stop but only one simultaneous SW instance per domain (plus that dodgy iFrame logic webkit has got going on)

So if neither Webkit or Edge do what my memory tells me then is it not a good performance idea? (Barring reduced hit rate on SW recycling)

EDIT 2

On third thoughts, the fact that everything in a ServiceWorker is Asynchronous or verbotten means Fetch, Push, Travel events can all multiplex to the same SW instance without performance degradation.

Oh Well, I'm back to "Stuffed if I know why no one is implementing the TravelManager :-("

FWIW The WebKit implementation of shared memory buffer must surely necessitate a synchronous API? Breaking one of the major premises of SW design?

Comment: Edge MVP here. Lemme ask the platform team. In the meantime, it's OK to provide background information but compared to your previous posts here I think there's just a bit too much... fluff, IYKWIM. It took me quite a while to find your actual question only for it to be a single sentence, and that's not good for a question on SO.

Comment: tl,dr; `Can someone please confirm that Edge implements multiple, specialist SW instances?`

Comment: My apologies. I'm carrying 2 years of baggage on this and find it hard to condense it. Thank-you for you response. Having said that, *please* also pass the link to the sscce to the Edge platform team. For context if nothing else.

Comment: Yeah, I completely understand your frustration on this. Will do. I'll see what I can do to edit your question into shape when I get the time.

Comment: I can only tell you so much about Edge's implementation of SW, but given the history surrounding the geolocation thing I think it's best we left that out since it's only tangentially related to the question at hand.

Comment: Ok, sounds reasonable

Answer (score 1):

While Edge does implement multiple service workers, it does *not* support specialist service workers for push, fetch, etc.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the conditions that yield multiple simultaneous "active" ServiceWorkers per domain? Also, if these SW instances are generic in their purpose can you confirm that there are no race condition and/or event sequencing issues with simultaneous processing of PUSH notifications and server FETCHing?

Comment: I'm guessing your ambiguous reply means "multiple service Worker instances over time with only ever one in 'active' state" as oppose to "multiple active, simultaneous, and parallel service worker instances for the same domain"? Please confirm.